# Return a string if localized string not found

Tags: ios, swift4

I would like to know how could I return a default string value if localized string of key is not found. here is my function to return the localized String.

```
func localizedStr(key: String) {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
}
```

I would like to return default string e.g. "foo" if the `key` is not found in localization file.

Comment: If there is no key/value for that key, `NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")` returns `key`. It's recommended to use for keys "notables strings which won't be values", like "__OK", "MyApp.OK", "s_Ok", etc.

Comment: I think `NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "") == key ? "foo" : NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")` will work, if your key is the same string you want to localised.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

Use the full

```
 NSLocalizedString(key: "key", value:"English string", comment: "")
```

If `key` is not found in your translated file, `value` is returned

**Long version**

Don't wrap `NSLocalizedString` in a function - while there's less code, you're losing valuable information for the localisation process.

1. you won't be able to use Xcode export an Xliff file for translation - only string literal `key`s in `NSLocalizedString` are included
2. Use a `value:` parameter with the English (or your base language) string. *This is used when no translation is found*, and means you don't need to have a base **Localizable.strings** file.
3. The `comment:` appears in the xliff file, and is useful for translators. Use this to give information about the context of the string being translated.

Answer (score 0):

You could give it default value like this, using `NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")` would return an Empty String if the `Key`  was not found so checking on it like this should do the trick.

```
  func localizedStr(key: String) {
         if NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "") == key {
          return "foo"
    }
    return  NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
```

Comment: But I get something returned when the key is not found, please see comment from @Larme above.

Comment: what do you get returned ?

Comment: key+someWeirdValue

Comment: usually its either empty string , or the key i've tested the case and returned a key so check if it key instead of isEmpty ill edit for you

Comment: According to the documentation about the return value: `If key is not found and value is nil or an empty string, returns key. If key is not found and value is non-nil and not empty, return value.`. So you shouldn't get an `isEmpty`.

Comment: yea, i just double tested it, it did return the key and i checked if the return value is == the key and gave me true, if this is the case i think it should work as i edited up there